# QT VS2017 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017

Версия QT - 5.12.3
Версия Visual Studio - 17

Собрал из исходников. Процесс установки выглядел следующим образом:
D:\Qt\src - папка с исходниками QT
D:\Qt\build - папка, куда положил собранную библиотеку

```
SET _ROOT = D:\Qt\src
SET PATH = %_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
configure -static -static-runtime -release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix D:\Qt\build
jom
jom install
```

Сборка прошла без ошибок. Содержимое директории с библиотекой: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил QtVsAddIn, установил туда путь к библиотеке, ошибок не возникло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при создании любого проекта Qt возникает следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако проект все же создается, но для него не генерируется хедер по умолчанию

Имя проекта: QtGuiApplication2

Не создается:

```
ui_QtGuiApplication2.h
```

Соответственно не получается использовать ui. Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Пробовал ставить разные vsix плагины (для 15 и 19 версии VS), проблема не решилась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В результате это оказался баг в расширении Qt для Visual Studio. Перешел на Qt creator, проблема ушла